# convert character mysql database 100 row every 20 seconds

Tags: php, sql

I have script , convert database from latin1 to utf
Converts all rows automatically at a once .
Because the database is very large 10 GB, I want to edit the file to convert the 100 row only every 20 seconds .
HOW I DO THIS ?

```
<?php

$dbconn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db("utf");

$sql = "ALTER DATABASE `utf` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
print "Database changed to UTF-8.\n";

$sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
$sql = "ALTER TABLE $table DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci, CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
print "$table changed to UTF-8.\n";
}

mysql_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: You are applying your change to the table, not to individual rows. All you can do is pause between tables.

Comment: @sergio - where i get `function sleep` ?

Comment: `sleep(5);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: @rjdown , are you mean i cannot do that for rows ? and how i make `pause between tables`

Comment: just put `sleep(20);` after `print "$table changed to UTF-8.\n";` to pause the script for 20 seconds

Comment: @rjdown , okay .. i don't understand well , `sleep(20);` this function means well pause all script for this time ? Regardless of the number of rows which converted . or what ?

Comment: It will pause this script for 20 seconds after each table, regardless of the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @rjdown , it's not working .. shows me this error `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceede` , so can i use `sleep(20);` with `for()` loop to sleep script every 100 rows only , not every table becouse some tables Contains Millions and thousands of rows

Comment: You shouldn't run this sort of thing from a browser, but if you really must, put `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your script. And no, you CANNOT LIMIT TO 100 ROWS AT A TIME!

Comment: You'd be better off running it from mysql command line instead of PHP. Or downloading the table, altering it offline (to prevent issues with locking), then just restore the table - if some of them aren't constantly being written to.

Comment: a 10 gig database is not large. just do it off line a swap it back in when done

Comment: @rjdown , okay i `CANNOT LIMIT TO 100 ROWS AT A TIME` , but `pause this script for 20 seconds after each table` that's not what i want to do ... i want `pause this script each 20 seconds For 5 seconds and then completes`, can i do that or not ? if i can , will there be a defect in the conversion or not ?

Comment: @EdHeal, Excuse me, can you explain more

Comment: @Benno , i cannot download it or edit it offline , i must make aconvert script not for this database only , i want convert a more

Comment: Do you own the database

Comment: @EdHeal, this script not for this database only but i will used it for more databases

Comment: If you own the database you can take it off line and do whatever in your own time. Get it back up to scratch. Otherwise do it on-line and your customers get the flak

Comment: @EdHeal, thanx but as i said to you ,  this script not for this database only but there more i want convert them